# Use Meteor without its templating library

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm building an app that uses only Polymer to structure the frontend. As a backend I'd really like to use Meteor with their Mongo realtime database.

I only need the part of Meteor that implements the DDP prototcol and provides the Mongo API to the client. Is it currently possible to remove the rest of the client libraries? I don't need jQuery, Blaze, Tracker and so forth.

I've already tried removing `meteor-platform` from the project, then adding all the packages `meteor-platform` consists of. This results into errors like `ReferenceError: Meteor is not defined`. It seems like this is not supported currently.

What I then used was [Asteroid](https://github.com/mondora/asteroid) which is really nice. But using it prevents me from using Meteor packages like GroundDB for example.

Reading on the [Meteor website](https://www.meteor.com/projects) gives me the feeling that it should be possible to use only some parts of Meteor, but this doesn't work for me.

What's the best way to tackle this problem?

**Edit**: I've uploaded a leaderboard example with the failing setup on [GitHub](https://github.com/amannn/meteor-without-blaze/tree/master). `Meteor.isServer` is causing the error. If you comment out the server stuff it works.

Comment: Can you post a reproduction in the form of an app? It seems like this should work and I'm interested in finding out why it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I've uploaded an example app to GitHub (please see the edited question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing two packages:

`meteor add meteor underscore`

The `meteor` package is the one that exposes `Meteor.isServer`.

Comment: You are right, it was the `meteor` package that was missing. Now I've removed `blaze`, `blaze-utils` and `jquery`. However, in the Chrome console there are still variables available like `Blaze` and `jQuery`. Are these necessary dependencies for a standard project? I've updated the repo and uploaded a deployed version to meteor-without-blaze.meteor.com

Comment: You should also remove htmljs, html-tools, UI, and templating.

Comment: Hmm, on Atmosphere I can see that `http` only uses meteor, underscore and url. url for its part only uses meteor and underscore. The removal of the packages you mentioned helped removing Blaze as far as I can see. Now I need to figure out a way to embed html content, since .html files aren't rendered at all anymore :). I could set `document.body.innerHTML` to something – is that the regular way when you don't have Blaze?

Comment: Btw. thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it, that you, as a core developer of Meteor, take the time for StackOverflow questions! :)

Comment: No problem! It's fun :] I was wrong about HTTP, you're right. And yes, since you don't have Blaze, .html files won't work. Meteor actually doesn't send any HTML to the client, it compiles everything into JS so you will either need to write your own JS code to insert HTML into the page, or write a plugin that compiles HTML into JS code that inserts it. This is what the `templating` package does: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/templating/plugin/compile-templates.js